# Looking for an equivalent to INTERSECT ALL in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, window-functions, row-number, intersect

I have a database which allows duplicates where the key is a string and the values are URLs. Here's the schema:
`CREATE TABLE Tags (p_tags TEXT, p_urls LONGVARCHAR);`

I would like to do a command like this in an efficient manner: `SELECT p_urls FROM Tags WHERE p_tags ='foo' INTERSECT ALL SELECT p_urls FROM Tags WHERE p_tags = 'bar';`

I am aware the `INTERSECT ALL` is not supported in sqlite, so my best effort right now is to do it by just counting up how many times each URL shows up in each p_tag and taking the minimum of the two. The trouble is that this is very slow - too slow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate `INTERSECT ALL` by adding another column to your resultset with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT p_urls, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_urls) rn 
  FROM Tags WHERE p_tags = 'foo' 
  INTERSECT
  SELECT p_urls, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_urls) rn 
  FROM Tags WHERE p_tags = 'bar'
)
SELECT p_urls FROM cte;
```

Or:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT p_urls, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_tags, p_urls) rn 
  FROM Tags 
  WHERE p_tags IN ('foo', 'bar')
)
SELECT p_urls 
FROM cte
GROUP BY p_urls, rn
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8e524add4e550896a59299fd0d6098c1).